# How can I search for web results specific to a country

Tags: google-search

In the old days I could (sometimes) get country specific results by using the google portal in that country (like google.co.uk). However, Google has removed this functionality. Also, that functionality did not work for small countries that did not have portals.

What I am trying to do is get results ONLY FROM WEB SITES IN THAT COUNTRY. In other words, I do not web pages about that country. I want web sites located IN that country.

For example, if I do the search "washing machines india" of my results 9 were .com sites and only a single result was a .in result. I want ALL my results to be .in results. Is there any way to restrict results to a particular country domain?

Comment: @pnuts This would only be for a single search, and for different searches I might want to do them for different countries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could set the site: filter to the top-level domain (TLD) of that country.  For example:

Search for [`foo site:uk`](https://www.google.com/search?q=foo%20site%3Auk) and you'll only get results from sites with the TLD name "uk", which limits results to the United Kingdom.